# Is it possible to avoid moving to indent level when hitting Enter in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code has a behaviour which I really dislike and is not present in Sublime Text.

When a cursor is on a line containing whitespace, it will jump to the indent level of the code above it when hitting Enter.

e.g. Suppose my cursor is as follows:

[image]

When I hit enter, I get the following:

[image]

I would like the cursor to behave exactly as it does in Sublime Text in this scenario, whereby it will remain to the very left when I hit Enter.

Here's the same scenario in Sublime Text:

[image]

and after hitting enter:

[image]

Is there any way to change VS Code's configuration or similar without resorting to extensions, to achieve the same behaviour as Sublime in this situation.

I'm aware that I could disable the "editor.autoIndent" setting, however this also disables auto-indentation completely which is undesirable.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)